# MessageBox Auto-Closing Within WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with a messagebox that is displaying, but then instantly closing itself within a WPF app. My code:

```
string messageTitle = Quarantine.Localizer.LocalizedStringForStatusCode("TITLE_GENERATEDSUPPORTFILE");
string message = "";
MessageBoxIcon messageIcon = MessageBoxIcon.Information;

try
{
    ServiceController.GenerateSupportArchive(archivePath);
    message = String.Format("{0} {1}", Quarantine.Localizer.LocalizedStringForStatusCode("DIALOG_GENERATEDSUPPORTFILE"), archivePath);
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    message = String.Format("{0}.\n\nError: {1}",
        Quarantine.Localizer.LocalizedStringForStatusCode("DIALOG_GENERATEDSUPPORTFILEFAIL"),
        exp.Message);
    messageIcon = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
}

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(message, messageTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, messageIcon);
```

The messsagebox displays correctly for the brief flash that I can see it on the screen, I'm just trying to figure out why it closes automatically before the OK button is pressed. This is within a WPF app using the MahApps.Metro community resources (Windowws 8 look).

Comment: System.Windows. **Forms** .MessageBox? Please don't drag Forms into a WPF Application. Use [System.Windows.MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx).

Comment: I have edited the code so that System.Windows.MessageBox is called instead of System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox. Same issue. Current code `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(message, messageTitle, MessageBoxButton.OK);`

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but with only one of my message boxes.